# Mysterious sum equal to $\frac{7(p^2-1)}{24}$ where $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, prime-numbers

Consider a prime number $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$ and $n_p$ denotes the remainder of $n$ upon division by $p$. Let $A_p=\{ a \in [[0,p]] \mid {(a+1)^2}_p<{a^2}_p\}$.

I Conjecture

$$\sum_{a \in A_p } a=\dfrac{7(p^2-1)}{24}$$

**Addition, a simpler way to prove equality after have answer **.

We denote the sequence $s_p=\sum_{a=1}^{p-1} a({(a+1)^2}_p-{a^2}_p)$.

By expanding, we verify that $s_p=-\sum_{a=1}^{p-1} {a^2}_p$.

We can also verify that if  $a\in A_p$, then

${(a+1)^2}_p-{a^2}_p  =({2a+1})_p-p$

and if  $a\notin A_p$, then

${(a+1)^2}_p-{a^2}_p =({2a+1})_p.$

We deduce $p\sum_{p \in A_p } a =\sum_{a=1}^{p-1} a ({2a+1})_p-s_p=\sum_{a=1}^{p-1} a ({2a+1})_p + \sum_{a=1}^{p-1} {a^2}_p$.

to finish, it is easy to calculate $\sum_{a=1}^{p-1} a ({2a+1})_p\quad  \forall p\in\mathbb N$ and $\sum_{a=1}^{p-1} {a^2}_p\quad \forall p\equiv 1\mod 4$

Comment: You define $n_p$, but is doesn't appear anywhere.

Comment: If $n \in [0, p]$ then $n_p = n$.

Comment: sorry error latex

Comment: So:   why $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4} \; \; ? \; \; $

Comment: I gave my list only for this kind of p

Comment: I have posted a related [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4639930/even-more-mysterious-sum-equaling-to-frac7p2-124-h-p-where-p-equ), which seems even more mysterious.

Comment: Enclose the code in ``` to make it come out right.

Comment: @joriki
   can you do it with Sage code ?

Comment: @Pascal: It doesn't matter which kind of code – all it does is to present the code verbatim instead of line-wrapping it like HTML.

Comment: I removed the code because it wasn't important

Comment: Amazing result , if correct. (+1)

Comment: @Peter The most incredible result is in this thread https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4639930/even-more-mysterious-sum-equaling-to-frac7p2-124-h-p-where-p-equ?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Let $g$ be the indicator function of $A_p$. I conjecture the following lemmas: Lemma1: $\sum_{k=1}^p g(k) = \frac{p-1}{2}$, i.e. $|A_p| = \frac{p-1}{2}$. Lemma2: $g(k)+g(p-k-1) = 1$ for all $k$ except for $k=\frac{p-1}{2}$ it is $0$. Using these lemmas I get the following (not sure if it's any help, though): $\sum_{k=1}^p g(k)k^2 = (p-1)\left(  \sum_{k=1}^p g(k)k  \right) - \frac{(2p-1)(p-1)(p-3)}{24}$. Well at least a correct sort of denominator appears :D If we can somehow get another relation between these power sums, maybe it yields the formula.

Comment: @ploosu2 Exactly one of $a$ or $p-1-a$ is in $A_p$. If $a\in A_p$ then $(p-1-a+1)^2_p=a^2_p>(a+1)^2_p=(p-1-a)^2_p$. So, I think $\sum g(k)$ should be $(p-1)/2$.

Comment: Also posted to MathOverflow, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/440995/mysterious-sum-equal-to-frac7p2-124-where-p-equiv-1-pmod4 as Pascal **should have noted**.

Comment: What happens with powers of primes ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I will leave several details for you to check, ask me if there are any issues with verifying them.

Let $$A_p=\{ a \in [[0,p-1]] \mid {(a+1)^2}_p<{a^2}_p\},$$

$$B_p=\{ a \in [[0,p-1]] \mid {(a+1)^2}_p>{a^2}_p\},$$
$$C_p=\{ a \in [[0,p-1]] \mid {(a+1)^2}_p={a^2}_p\}.$$
Then $A_p \cup B_p \cup C_p = [[0,p-1]]$. Check that $C_p$ is the singleton set $\{(p-1)/2 \}$.

Now, note that $a \in A_p \iff (p-1-a) \in B_p$ (Verify!).

Let $A_p' = A_p \cap [[0,(p-1)/2]]$, $B_p' = B_p \cap [[0,(p-1)/2]]$.

Then $A_p = A'_p \cup A''_p$ where $A_p'' = \{ (p-1)-b | b\in B_p' \}$.

Final thing to note is that $A_p' = \{ \lfloor \sqrt{jp} \rfloor | 1 \leq j \leq (p-5)/4 \}$, so $|A_p'| = (p-5)/4$ and $|B_p'| = (p+3)/4$.

Now, we just do a computation:

\begin{align}
\sum_{a \in A_p'} a + \sum_{a \in A_p''} a &= \sum_{a \in A_p'} a + \sum_{a \in B_p'} [(p-1) - a] \\ &= 2 \sum_{a \in A_p'} a + \sum_{a \in B_p'} (p-1) - \sum_{a=0}^{(p-3)/2} a \\ &= 2 \sum_{j=0}^{(p-5)/4} \lfloor \sqrt{jp} \rfloor + \frac{(p-1)(p+3)}4 - \frac{(p-3)(p-1)}8
\end{align}

Now, consider the subset of $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$
$$\eqalign{
  &\left\{(t,j)\ \bigg|\ 1 \leq j \leq \frac{p-5}{4}\ \hbox{and}\ 
                    1 \leq t \leq \sqrt{jp} \right\}\cr
  &\qquad\qquad= \left\{(t,j)\ \bigg|\ 1 \leq t \leq \frac{p-3}{2}\ \hbox{and}\ 
                     \frac{t^2}{p} \leq j \leq \frac{p-5}{4} \right\}\cr}
$$
Comparing both cardinalities we get (q.r. = quadratic residues)
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=0}^{(p-5)/4} \lfloor \sqrt{jp} \rfloor &= \sum_{t=1}^{(p-3)/2} \left \{ \frac {(p-5)} 4 - \left \lfloor \frac{t^2} p  \right \rfloor \right \} \\ &= \frac{(p-3)(p-5)}{8} - \sum_{t=1}^{(p-3)/2} \frac{t^2} p + \sum_{t=1}^{(p-3)/2} \frac{t^2 \pmod p} p \\ &= \frac{(p-3)(p-5)}{8} - \frac{(p-1)(p-2)(p-3)}{24p} \\ &\ \ \ + \frac{\text{Sum of q.r. mod p}- ((p-1)/2)^2 \pmod p}p
\end{align}
Now, if $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, then $((p-1)/2)^2 \equiv (3p+1)/4 \pmod p$ and sum of quadratic residues is $p(p-1)/4$.
Thus,
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=0}^{(p-5)/4} \lfloor \sqrt{jp} \rfloor &= \frac{(p-3)(p-5)}{8} - \frac{(p-1)(p-2)(p-3)}{24p} + \frac{p(p-1)- (3p+1)}{4p} \\ &= \frac{(p-1)(p-5)}{12}.
\end{align}
Now, the final sum is
\begin{align}
\sum_{a \in A_p} a &= \frac{(p-1)(p-5)}{6} + \frac{(p-1)(p+3)}4 - \frac{(p-3)(p-1)}8 \\ &= \frac{7(p^2-1)}{24}.
\end{align}
Here are [two](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c146t416f146h150712_i_11) [problems](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c146t416f146h150713_i_12) employing similar techniques. (That is where I learnt this method from)

Comment: Thank you very much for this beautiful proof. I took my time to understand

Comment: I have added a numerical result on MO  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/440995/mysterious-sum-equal-to-frac7p2-124-where-p-equiv-1-pmod4     that I think is interesting

Comment: @Pascal That numerical result is the same as this one + the other linked question.

Comment: But The equality $\sum_{n \in A_p} n=\dfrac{7p^2 -12p+5}{24}+\dfrac{1}{p}\sum_{n=1}^{p-1}{n^2}_p$ seems to be true for odd values of $p\geq 3$ , but not necessarily for prime numbers

Comment: @Pascal Notice that $(-n)^2 = n^2$, so your sum $\sum_{n=1}^{p-1} n^2_p = 2\sum_{n=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}} n^2_p$ is just the sum of quadratic residues mod $p$, and the rest is easy.

Comment: I expect this can be adapted for the $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ case  using H. Holden 
$$ \frac{h(-p)}{2 - (2|p)}   = \frac{1}{6}(p-1)(p-2) - 2 \sum_{k=1}^{(p-3)/4} 
  \left\lfloor \sqrt{kp} \right\rfloor
  $$

Comment: @Rijul Saini  I have suggested another way that I believe is simpler

Comment: @Pascal Yes your solution is very nice indeed.