# Even more mysterious sum equaling to $\frac{7(p^2-1)}{24} - h(-p)$ where $p \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$

Tags: number-theory, class-field-theory

This is a direct follow-up to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4639883/mysteriuos-sum-equal-to-dfrac7p2-124-where-p-equiv-1-pmod4#4639883) question, which I think is interesting enough to be a separate problem. Please check that post out too in case there are ideas there that might transfer here.

In the post linked, they found numerically that for odd primes $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$, the sum of all $n$ such that $(n^2+2n+1 \  \mathrm{mod} p) < (n^2 \ \mathrm{mod} p)$ is exactly $\frac{7}{24}(p^2-1)$. It is natural to generalise this for $p \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$, and you won't believe what I found! Here's some Sage code:

```
x = var('x')
for p in prime_range(6, 1001):
    if p % 4 != 3: continue
    ns = [n for n in range(p) if (n^2 + 2*n + 1) % p < (n^2) % p] # your condition
    R.<t> = NumberField(x^2 + p) # setup Q[sqrt(-p)]
    assert sum(ns) == (p^2 - 1) * 7 / 24 - R.class_number() # observed = ???
```

As annotated above, I conjecture that for odd primes $p > 3$ satisfying $p \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$, we have

$$
\sum_{0 \leq n < p} n \cdot [(n+1)^2\,\mathrm{mod}\, p \leq n^2\,\mathrm{mod}\, p] = \frac{7}{24}(p^2-1)-h(\sqrt{-p}).
$$

Feel free to play with the Sage script above. I suspect that there might be some "symmetry" or relation with quadratic residues, since it is well known that the class number is (-1 / p) times sum of n * (n | p).

I will set a bounty when I can.

Comment: Yes, this might be finally a simple method to calculate the class number. Check this desmos: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gnfkwahnbf  you rotate and shift by 1; they line up almost perfectly only differ in three places: $0$, middle and $p$.

Comment: @ploosu2 This method won't be computationally "simple" at all, though it's definitely a fun way. Can you explain your desmos? I don't think I understand the formulas.

Comment: The function $g$ is indicator of $A_p$ and the first points are just the points $(k, g(k))$ for $k=0,1,\dots, p$ and the second ones are them rotated 180 degrees and moved so that they overlap. Had to move one step off, so they like start from I guess $p-1$ goes over $0$ and so on.

Comment: PARI/GP will be a much better tool for this purpose than Desmos.

Comment: What is $h(-p)$ and why do you have $h(-\sqrt{p})$ later ?

Comment: @peter Ah it’s the imaginary class number, you get what the notation means. Look at my code, i annotated with (English not math) explanations.

Comment: Combining the techniques from my answer in the linked problem, with Will Jagy's formula below, should yield this. Note that the only thing mysterious in the calculation with $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ will be the sum of quadratic residues which should exactly be taken care of by that class number formula.

Comment: @RijulSaini Yes, once you reduced it to sum of quadratic residues it's well known to be related to class number, as I noted in my post already :) Thank you for your answer! What a nice formula.

Comment: Well, it works. Highlights include, with prime $q = 4 w + 3, $    $$ \sum_{j=1}^w  \left\lfloor \sqrt{jq} \right\rfloor = 2w^2 -\sum_{x=1}^{2w}   \left\lfloor \frac{ x^2}{q} \right\rfloor   $$ and $$       \sum_{x=1}^{2w}   \left\lfloor \frac{ x^2}{q} \right\rfloor = \frac{(q-1)(q-11)}{24}  + \frac{1+ h(   \sqrt {-q} )}{2}                    $$

Comment: @WillJagy   Is the formula $\sum_{j=1}^w \left\lfloor \sqrt{jq} \right\rfloor = 2w^2 -\sum_{x=1}^{2w} \left\lfloor \frac{ x^2}{q} \right\rfloor$ also true for p=1+4k?

Comment: @Pascal  if you mean to take $w = (p-1)/ 4$  then yes.